# NodeJS https request needs excessive memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to load the json of this url https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json . The file has over 600MB to download.

I am using this code in a lambda function:

The lambda function is setup with a timeout of 10min and 3008MB of memory. But the function is trying to use more than that.

```
let res = await doRequest2('https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json');

function doRequest2(url) {
  console.log("doRequest");
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 const https = require("https");
 const url = "https://pricing.us-east-   1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json";
 https.get(url, res => {
 res.setEncoding("utf8");
 let body = "";
 res.on("data", data => {
  body += data;
  });
  res.on("end", () => {
   body = JSON.parse(body);
 resolve(body);
 console.log(body);
   });
    res.on("error", () => {
 console.log("Error");
 reject("error");
     });
 });

});
}
```

How can the json download need so much memory?

Comment: instead of downloading ,you can just stream your data to destination..like  res.on("data", data => {
 response.pipe(data)
  });..Based on requirement

Comment: @BittuS I would like to save the file to AWS S3, do you know if I can stream it to there?

Answer (score 1):

The memory is being used for so much more than just holding a copy of the json file. It is running your actual program, maintaining a https link and all of the various things that computers do.

The download is actually quite a bit of heavy lifting. Due to the size of file the memory usage can be a bit spikey.

I have actually managed to get your code working, but only one in four times, because as soon as the memory usage is maxed, the lambda will cut out.

This job seems to be a little to big for what lambda can handle (reliably at least).

**NB** - I removed a previous answer pointing to the disk space limit available in the temp folder as after my own testing I could see this was not the case.